# Sitecore 8.2, Adding a ComputedIndexField to Solr configuration

Tags: c#, solr, sitecore, sitecore8

I need to add a ComputedIndexField to my Solr Configuration 
Doing so by creating a config patch containing the following

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>          
          <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
            <field fieldName="SomeFieldName">
              Type, Dll
            </field>
          </fields>         
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

But i kept getting the error. Even though this was the format the documentation was suggesting.

```
Could not find property 'fieldMap' on object of type: System.String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem: 
The naming of my custom config was making it load before the nodes that it was trying to patch. I fixed it by changing the name so that they would load AFTER the node.